# Select where not exists / count(otherRecord) = 0

Tags: soql

I have a custom object with a custom field called Key__c and I have created the same Key__c field in the Account object. The Custom Object has a lookup relationship towards the account. I would need to perform the following query:

> Find all the Account objects for which there's no record of type
>   custom object  with field key_c. (SELECT Name from Account where not
>   exists (Select 1 from Custom_Object where Custom_Object.Key__c =
>   Account.Key__c)

How do you model this in SOQL?

Comment: Is there any relationship between the custom field and account? SOQL doesn't allow joins between objects unless there is a look-up or master-detail field linking them. It sounds like you might want to make that key field into a junction object in a many-to-many relationship, or else break this up into two queries.

Comment: there is a lookup relationship between Custom Object and Account yes

Comment: The more I look at this, the more I think that you'll need to approach the overall problem (the one you're trying to solve by creating this query) from a different direction. SOQL doesn't allow us to compare fields to one another (i.e. `Custom_Object__c.Key__c = Account.Key__c` is not allowed), so this would need to be broken into at least 2 separate queries. One of those queries would need to query all of the records on one of your two objects, which raises concerns of query selectivity. Can you please go into more detail about the overall problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I basically need to write a trigger that does the following 1) Crete a case the first time a record with Key__C is ever inserted in my instance (and attach it to the account). 2) Send an email for those record for which there is no Account with Key__C

Comment: Do you automatically create a new `Account` record when a new value of `Key__c` is encountered, or is that what you're creating the `Case` for? Does a `Custom_Object__c` record always have `Key__c` populated? Is a `Custom_Object__c` record always associated to an `Account`, or is it only associated to an `Account` when there is an `Account` with a matching value of `Key__c`? If `Custom_Object__c` is only associated to an `Account` when `Key__c` is the same, then a query for `Custom_Object__c` records that aren't associated to any `Account` should work (and is much easier to write).

Comment: No I can't create always create an Account__c, I don't have all the fields. The lookup relationship is only populated when there is a matching account. Can you help me write those two queries?

Comment: @Edmondo1984 This is getting a bit long for comments, I've [created a chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56654/discussion-between-derekf-and-edmondo1984) so we can continue discussing details.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that there is no good translation from your target query into SOQL. SOQL does not allow comparing a field to another field. There is a way to do something similar, but it would involve querying either all of your `Accounts` or all of your `Custom_Object__c` records (and Salesforce strongly discourages querying *all* records of any object).

Summing up the information from the comments and our chat log:

- `Custom_Object__c` records always have `Key__c` populated
- `Custom_Object__c` records are automatically associated to an `Account` only if there is an existing `Account` that has a matching value of `Key__c`
- If there isn't already an `Account` record with a matching `Key__c` value, it isn't possible for you to create a new `Account` at the time when new `Custom_Object__c` records are inserted
- This isn't a problem of associating `Custom_Object__c` records to `Account` records once the `Account` has `Key__c` populated

Your goals are:

1. Send an email to alert people when `Custom_Object__c` records are inserted, and there isn't an `Account` that has a matching `Key__c` value
2. Do some form of notification when an `Account`, that previously didn't have any related `Custom_Object__c` records, changes to have at least one `Custom_Object__c` related to it

We want to do this in a way that uses so-called 'selective' queries. In a nutshell that means that we want to write queries that return as few results as possible, use as many indices as possible, and avoid using `!=` and `null`.

Obtaining the collection of `Custom_Object__c` records that don't currently match with any `Account` is a fairly straight-forward process. I don't think there's a way to make a query do all the work and still have it be selective, so we'll need to do some work outside of the query (in Apex).

```
// I'm assuming that this will be part of a trigger
// The general process we'll follow here is:
// 1 - Iterate over the incoming Custom_Object__c records, and store them in a
//   Map<String, List<Custom_Object__c>>.
//   The key of the map will be values of the Key__c field
// 2 - Use the map's keyset to query for Accounts with matching values of Key__c
// 3 - Iterate over the results of the query, and store the Key__c values in a separate set
// 4 - Use methods of the Set class to arrive at the collection of incoming Custom_Object__c
//   records where there isn't an Account record with a matching Key__c

Map<String, List<Custom_Object__c>> keysToCustomObjRecs = new Map<String, List<Custom_Object__c>>();

for(Custom_Object__c custObj :trigger.new){
    // This if block only concerns itself with creating a new List to put Custom_Object__c
    //   records into when we encounter a new value of Key__c.
    // Adding records to that List would be common to the inside and outside
    //   of the if block, so I just add to the list outside of the if block to keep things
    //   DRY.
    if(!keysToCustomObjRecs.containsKey(custObj.Key__c)){
        keysToCustomObjRecs.put(custObj.Key__c, new List<Custom_Object__c>());
    }

    keysToCustomObjRecs.get(custObj.Key__c).add(custObj);
}

Set<String> accountKeysSet = new Set<String>();

for(Account acct: [SELECT Id, Key__c FROM Account WHERE Key__c IN :keysToCustomObjRecs.keySet()]){
    accountKeysSet.add(acct.Key__c);
}

// We can use set.removeAll on a map's keySet to effectively remove Custom_Object__c
//   records from the map that we know will match to an Account
keysToCustomObjRecs.keySet().removeAll(accountKeysSet);

List<Custom_Object__c> custObjsWithNoMatchingAccount = new List<Custom_Object__c>();

// Add all of our remaining custom object lists from our map into the aggregate list
for(List<Custom_Object__c> custObjList : keysToCustomObjRecs.values()){
    custObjsWithNoMatchingAccount.addAll(custObjList);
}
```

Your second goal is a bit harder. To avoid needing to query all of the `Custom_Object__c` records to figure out which `Accounts` don't have any related records, we'd want to use a rollup summary field. Since the relationship between `Custom_Object__c` and `Account` is a lookup relationship, we can't use Salesforce-provided rollup-summary fields.

You could use [Andrew Fawcett's Declarative lookup rollup summary tool](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries), but that creates its own trigger. When one object has more than one trigger that fires on the same events (e.g. `after update`), Salesforce doesn't guarantee the order in which the triggers are executed (and the order of execution will be important to us). You could copy/paste the generated trigger code into your existing trigger, but that removes a big part of the functionality of the DLRS tool (that is, being able to change the rollup declaratively).

Instead, we can just make our own rollup code (it ends up being pretty short) using a query and the `COUNT()` aggregate function.

```
// I'll assume that you have a collection of Account Ids.
// As long as you meet that requirement, this code could be placed in either an Account
//   trigger or a Custom_Object__c trigger.
// I also assume that the API name of your lookup field to Account is 'Account__c'.
List<Account> accountsToUpdate = new List<Account>();
for(AggregateResult result :[SELECT Account__c, COUNT(Id) relatedRecords FROM Custom_Object__c WHERE Account__c IN :accountIds GROUP BY Account__c]){
    // We can use the SObject constructor to set the Id field.
    // This allows us to update an existing record without querying for it first
    accountsToUpdate.add(new Account(
        // using .get() is the only way to retrieve fields from an AggregateResult.
        // Doing so will return a plain Object, so we need to type-cast
        Id = (Id)result.get('AccountId'),
        Number_of_Custom_Objects__c = (Double)result.get('relatedRecords')
    );
}

// After this DML update, your Accounts will have an updated count of how many related
// Custom_Object__c records they have.
update accountsToUpdate;
```

Given that your goal is to determine which `Accounts` had 0 related records, but now have more than 0, you'll want to figure out which `Accounts` have 0 related records before updating the related record count. That's a pretty simple query.

```
[SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Number_of_Custom_Objects__c = 0]
```

After your count update, you'll use another simple query to figure out which `Accounts` just got their first related records.

```
// Using != is bad for performance, and bad for selectivity.
// So, instead of Number_of_Custom_Objects__c != 0, we can use Number_of_Custom_Objects__c > 0, 
//   which should give us the same end result.
[SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Number_of_Custom_Objects__c > 0 AND Id IN :<collection of Ids from the previous query>]
```

The one remaining piece of the puzzle is to calculate the count of related `Custom_Object__c` records on existing `Accounts`. The rollup code above will calculate this for you from this point forward, but you'll need to update your existing `Accounts` yourself.

This can be done via anonymous apex, fairly simply, using a query on `Account` and a left outer join (a.k.a. a parent-child subquery).

```
// You should adjust the date literal to match whatever time it is that you started
//   running this anonymous apex for the first time.
// This will prevent us from updating the same accounts over and over again.
// You might also need to adjust the LIMIT 5000 (either upwards or downwards) to perform
//   as many updates at once as you can (the maximum number for LIMIT will be 10000).
// For the inner query, the object name typically changes to the plural 
//   (Custom_Object -> Custom_Objects), and the __c becomes __r.
// Re-run this in anonymous apex until the debug log shows 0 query rows returned.
List<Account> accountsToUpdate = [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Custom_Objects__r) FROM Account WHERE LastModifiedDate < '2017-04-07T13:25:00.000Z' LIMIT 5000];

for(Account acct :accountsToUpdate){
    acct.Number_of_Custom_Objects__c = acct.Custom_Objects__r.size();
}

update accountsToUpdate;
```